# how to ensure that payload is in specific format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, azure-functions

How do we enforce that a `DateTime` passed into the method below is in a specific format: `yyyyMMddHHmmssnnn`?

```cs
    [FunctionName("OnGenerateBossNameHttpTriggered")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "OnGenerateBossNameHttpTriggered")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BossFileNameComponents>(requestBody);
        return new OkObjectResult(FileNameGenerator.Generate(data));
    }
```

The definition of the data model that I am accepting is this:

```cs
public class BossFileNameComponents
{
    public string PracticeCode { get; set; }
    public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }
    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string DateOfService { get; set; }
    public string PatientIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string EncounterIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public DateTime TieBreaker { get; set; }
}
```

How do we validate that the `TieBreaker` provided by the consumer is in a specific format: `yyyyMMddHHmmssnnn?`

Comment: After the deserialization, you can check if the TieBreaker is a valid DateTime, if he sends an invalid DateTime the TieBraker will be the Date Min Value

Comment: `DateTime` is a binary value, it has no format. The defacto JSON standard is ISO8601, not what you posted here. You'd have to use a custom date format with JSON.NET to generate what you want.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos are you referring to this line: `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BossFileNameComponents>(requestBody);`  where i would use custom serialization to grab the datetime in the correct format? if so, is my model incorrect in defining that field as a datetime? `public DateTime TieBreaker { get; set; }`

Comment: The *format* you want is incorrect. The defacto standard is ISO8601, ie `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.......`. You can still specify a custom format using Json serialization settings as described in [Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the reason for the unconventional formatting is because `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` must be part of a file name, and must have no special characters

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' If you want to use a DateTime in a file name you would need to convert the DateTime to a string anyway. There you can apply your format, e.g `var filename = $"Myfile{TieBreaker:yyyyMMddHHmmssnnn}.dat";`

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' the file name format concerns only the code that reads/writes the file. It shouldn't affect how dates are exchanged between services or functions. You should use `String.Format()` and the format you posted when you need to read/write to the file.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, DateTime is a binary value. It has no format. Formats apply only when a string gets parsed into a DateTime or when a string gets generated from a DateTime value.

JSON has no standard date representation but the defacto standard is ISO8601, ie `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK`. That's what JSON.NET understands and produces by default.

That's just the default though. As [Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) explains, the format can be changed by passing a [JsonSerializerSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) class with a custom [DateFormatString](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm) to [DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_1.htm) :

```
var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings 
             {
                  DateFormatString="yyyyMMddHHmmssnnn"
             };
var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BossFileNameComponents>(requestBody,settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom JsonConverter, see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: There's no need to use a custon JsonConverter, just a custom date format string.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' why do you want to use such an unconventional format in the first place?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you give an example of what you mean by custom date format string and NOT jsonconverter?